# passing a value through the edit text to be consulted in the GET of the interface

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

ok soo this is my interface code:

```
interface CodeService {

@GET("sro-rastro/{code}")
fun list(@Path("code") code : String = "LB524259080HK"
) : Call<Code> 
}
```

And that is my activity getting the value from EditText

```
 binding.btNewPackage.setOnClickListener {
        var TrackingNumber = binding.etTrackingNumber.text.toString()
        
    }
```

so, i want a way to get the value of TrackingNumber and pass it in the interface instead of String = "LB524259080HK"
it is my first time using Retrofit and i'm pretty lost at how i would pass the value to my interface.

Comment: You need to create an instance of this interface using retrofit. And the you can call this `list` function using that instance. You can go through any tutorial on Retrofit and understand the basic flow.

Comment: Ok so i'm using that: 
 { val call = RetrofitInitializer().codeService().list(  Here  ) }

but I want to put the TrackingNumber where is 'here' (please be in mind that i don't have that "Here" in my code, it's just an example, in my code is hard coded with the number
But the TrackingNumber comes from my AddActivity
I want to retrieve data with the intent and pass to mainActivity to pass to my list function
Sorry i didn't explain the data was coming from a 2nd activity

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether your structure is right calling the API from `MainActivity` instead of `AddActivity` because the `EditText` is defined there. Anyway, what you can do is use `SharedPreferences` to save the data of `trackingNumber` whenever `btNewPackage` is clicked like this:

```
binding.btNewPackage.setOnClickListener {
    val trackingNumber = binding.etTrackingNumber.text.toString()

    val sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("preference_file_key", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    with (sharedPref.edit()) {
        putString("tracking_number", trackingNumber)
        apply()
    }
}
```

And at the time of calling the API, you can simply fetch the `trackingNumber` using `SharedPreferences` and pass it along like this:

```
val sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("preference_file_key", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
val trackingNumber = sharedPref.getString("tracking_number", "")
        
val call = RetrofitInitializer().codeService().list(trackingNumber)
```